# How to account for user-entered typos in a JavaScript prompt?

Tags: javascript, html, user-interface

First off, hello! I'm new to this website so I apologize for any errors that I make posting-wise.

I am in a web technology class where we are learning JavaScript. In a previous class we learned HTML5 and CSS. Our current assignment is to make a webpage that will either display 1 of 3 images or no images when the user enters the corresponding word in the prompt window.

I was wondering if there was a way to account for user-entered typos? For example, I have in the code "Spn" but was wondering if there was a way to easily make it so that if a user were to enter "Son" by mistake, they would still be shown the image.
Is there a way to do this without having to add a separate if statement?

Below is the code I have so far, which includes my little "test" to see if I could do this. I thought it had worked when I only had two items (ex: "Spn, "spn"), but when I added a third it stopped working, and now it isn't working again. I may have very well been mistaken that there was ever a success, though.

Oh, also, we are only allowed to use JavaScript, HTML, and CSS. So if you have a solution that is jquery (I have no idea what that is), then thank-you, but I'm afraid I can't use it.

Please let me know if there is any other information that you need and I will gladly supply it to you. Thank-you very much for your help, I very much appreciate it!
-Carly

---

**JavaScript Code (file name is switch.js):**

```
var temp = "None";


function choose()
    {
        temp = prompt("Spn, DW, SH, or None?");

            if (temp == "Spn","spn")
                {
                    document.getElementById("picture").src="first.jpg";
                    document.getElementById("sub").innerHTML="Supernatural";
                    document.getElementById("picture").style.visibility="visible";
                };
            if (temp == "DW","dw","Dw")
                {
                    document.getElementById("picture").src="second.jpg";
                    document.getElementById("sub").innerHTML="Doctor Who";
                    document.getElementById("picture").style.visibility="visible";
                };
            if (temp == "SH","sh","Sh")
                {
                    document.getElementById("picture").src="third.jpg";
                    document.getElementById("sub").innerHTML="Sherlock";
                    document.getElementById("picture").style.visibility="visible";
                };
            if (temp == "None","none")
                {
                    document.getElementById("picture").src="blank.jpg";
                    document.getElementById("sub").innerHTML="Click button to reveal image";
                    document.getElementById("picture").style.visibility="hidden";
                };
    }
```

---

**HTML Code (file name is userchoice.html):**

```
<!doctype html>
<html>

<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
    <script src="switch.js"></script>
    <title>What is this not working I'm going to cry</title>
</head>

<body>
    <h1>SuperWhoLock</h1>
    <h2 id="sub">Click button to reveal image</h2>

    <div id="picblock">
        <img src="blank.jpg" id="picture">
    </div>

    <div id="buttons">
        <button onclick="choose()">Choose Picture</button>
    </div>
</body>

</html>
```

---

**CSS code (the file name is style.css):**

```
body  
    { background-image:url('background.jpg');
    }




h1
    { width: 25%;
    text-align: center;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    background: black;
    color: white;
    }

h2
    { width: 25%;
    text-align: center;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    background: white;
    color: black;
    }

#picblock
    { width: 25%;
    text-align: center;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    }

#picture
    {visibility:hidden;
    }


#buttons
    { text-align: center;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Barring the foray into putting intelligence in the code, I will give a rather simplistic approach, detailed below:

1. Since you are the one who is deciding that "Son" should pull up the image ideally meant for "Spn", we should use a mapping that is created by you yourself. We can have something like this:

`

```
var spn = "Spn", dw ="DW",sh="SH";

//creating a custom mapping
var dict = {
"Son":spn,
"Sln":spn,
"Spn":spn,
"DW":dw,
"DE":dw,
"SH":sh

}

//Your if would look like:
temp = (dict && dict[temp])?dict[temp]:null;

if (temp && temp.toLower() == "spn")
```

`
2. For creating that dictionary, you will just have to consider the characters around the letter that you are typing.

**Note**: This approach assumes you have only these three things to compare. If you want a more generic solution that should work beyond Spn,DW,SH, None, please let me know.

Comment: +1 This is a good answer.  You should make a comment here if you don't completely understand it or are having trouble implementing it. For example if you don't know what an object is in javascript you could ask what the var dict is or what dict[temp] does. (sorry if you knew this already I'm just not sure how new you are.) Here is something you might find confusing to begin with and it has to do with the ? and : it's called the ternary operator. Here's an explanation of it http://www.codecademy.com/glossary/javascript/ternary-operator. It's basically an if else statement.

Comment: Thank-you both for your help! I am new to JavaScript and we have learned so far about functions, variables, and conditionals. I don't really know much else, and I am trying hard to understand, but this is very confusing to me, haha.

Oh goodness, even the link is confusing. I appreciate the help! Hopefully if I stare at these resources you have both given me long enough I will be able to figure it out ^-^

Comment: Oh, sorry for the double post, but if it helps this is the "textbook" that we are using: http://eloquentjavascript.net/contents.html

Comment: @Carlyndra that text book is enough to understand the code here. come back to this once you are done with your course and may be you get the hunch then